# Trying to locate the file that contains the code for index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit

Tags: core

I'd assume the file to be `Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` looking at the `editAction()` function but this seems to not be the case.

Could somebody point me at the correct file location please.

Comment: yes this correct location.But check any extension is override the extension

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct place, but it would seem something is overriding that controller.

Do a search in all your modules for another `ProductController.php` or potentially search for `editAction()` but that would return a lot of results.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34721/753) for ways in which you may find a URL to be rewritten.  One possibility is that another module is rewriting the controller, so search for:

```
before="Mage_Adminhtml"
```

inside `app/code/local` and `app/code/community` to find `config.xml` files for third party modules which are rewriting `Adminhtml` module controllers (common when building modules which include admin functionality in order to continue to use the standard admin `frontName`).

Answer (score 0):

In the file:
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php

Go to dispatch() function and at the top write:

Mage::log(get_class($this),null,'path.log'); and hit your functionality that uses the controller.

With logging enabled var/log/path.log should have the class name that your action is present in.