# Change magento checkout URL

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, url, url-rewrite

I want to change/translate the default magento cart and checkout URL.
I use the default Magento checkout.

So http://www.(domain).com/cart will be
http://www.(domain).com/winkelmand

and

http://www.(domain).com/checkout will be
http://www.(domain).com/bestellen

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create your own extension to achieve this funcitonality

here is very good example by [Jonathan Hussey](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/how-to-re-write-the-default-urls) Also one more which is similar like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722841/custom-url-for-magentos-basket-page

it is just for your knowledge and to used perfect solution.

*i am not associate with any how with this user*

hope this will sure work for you.