# custom url rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, nginx, catalog-url-rewrite

I'm using magento 1.9, nginx and want to customer url rewrite without 301 or 302.

i.e

```
/customer/account/login/
```

need to rewrite to

`/login/`.

**Changes the default log-in address /customer/account/login/, it can be accessed at /login/.**

Please response asap.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking to rewrite URLs I found [this question and answer helpful](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/how-to-re-write-the-default-urls).

You can also have a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772720/is-there-a-way-to-change-login-page-url-in-magento), or simply try out [this open source module](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_CustomUrls) found on github.

Hope one of these helps you!

Comment: I used one module and it works.. We can change the url as we want.. i.e. https://www.example.com/sales/order/history/ to https://www.example.com/customer/sales/track/ or https://www.example.com/customer/sales/order/history/ or https://www.example.com/order/history/ ...anything without updating single line code.